# Are there any DNS Server as a Service services available in the cloud?

Tags: amazon-web-services, dns, cloud, saas

It's a bit of a special use case.

I currently have several DNS servers running on my computer to do some special routing/redirection within my home network. I'm curious as to whether something like this is offered as a service, in the cloud.

I'm well aware that there are services like Google Cloud DNS and Amazon Route 53. But I think these are usually meant for managing DNS entries on your domain and how they resolve for everyone on the public internet (I could be wrong).

I'm really looking for something to manage DNS entries that will only resolve for only anyone configured to use a specifc DNS server.

Thinking about it some more, an analogous use case may be a small company that would rather have their DNS server in a (private?) cloud than manage it locally.

I realize running a DNS server is not that hard, I'm just curious as to whether something like this is available as a service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the webpage for [Amazon Route 53](http://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2014/11/05/amazon-route-53-now-supports-private-dns-with-amazon-vpc/),

> You can now use Amazon Route 53, AWS's highly available and scalable DNS service, to easily manage your internal domain names with the same simplicity, security, and cost effectiveness that Route 53 already provides for external DNS names. You can use the Route 53 Private DNS feature to manage authoritative DNS within your Virtual Private Clouds (VPCs), so you can use custom domain names for your internal AWS resources without exposing DNS data to the public Internet.

So the answer to your question is: **yes**